# Skipping type hints in documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx, type-hinting, autodoc, sphinx-napoleon

Let's consider the following function:

```py
def f(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    """Get sum of two integers.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : int
        first integer
    y : int
        second integer

    Returns
    -------
    int
        sum of the provided integers
    """
    return x + y
```

While documenting with Sphinx (v3.2.1), the documentation is generated in the following form:

[image]

However, I don't see a point to show type hints as in `f(x: int, y:int) -> int` in the heading of function documentation, and also in the `Parameters` section. In this case, it doesn't really matter, but it makes it very unreadable with functions with 4-5 arguments. Is there a way to skip the type hint? Like, I'll prefer if the heading is just `f` or `f(x, y)`.

I expected this has something to do with `add_function_parentheses`, but setting it as `False` in `conf.py` didn't have any effect that I've noticed.

A related issue is that if type hint is long, may be like `typing.Union` with multiple long descriptions, where I do not want to use `typing.Any`, i often write those in the docstring across multiple lines, adhering to maximum line limit. In those cases, the `Parameters` section shows that the type is what is in the first line, and next lines are just descriptions. I'm not attaching an example of this issue, as I am not sure whether these are same or not. If they are, please let me know and I'll update with an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option [`autodoc_typehints`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/2.0/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_typehints) for `sphinx.ext.autodoc`. This has 3 options: `none`, `description` and `signature` (default). Using either of `none` or `description` will hide type hints in the header line. The only difference I can find in between these two is that if docstrings do not contain type suggestions, `description` will still show them in the documentation collecting from type hints.

To use this, following changes are required in `conf.py`:

1. add `sphinx.ext.autodoc` in `extensions` (if not done already)
2. set `autodoc_typehints = "none"`

Answer (score 1):

A handler for the [`autodoc-process-signature`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#event-autodoc-process-signature) event can change signatures and return annotations of functions and methods.

Below is a simple example. If you add this code to conf.py, all signatures and return annotations are removed from the output.

```
def fix_sig(app, what, name, obj, options, signature, return_annotation):
    return ("", "")
 
def setup(app):
    app.connect("autodoc-process-signature", fix_sig)
```

Comment: Thanks. This changed the header to `f()`. I'm fine with it, though from your words, I expected just `f`. Can you offer some suggestions about the 2nd problem?

Comment: You are right. The parentheses are not removed. I have no solution for that

Comment: For the second problem, please post a separate question.

Comment: Sure. Will create a new thread, but have to create an MCVE first. While investigating options based on your solution to get just `f` or `f(x, y)`, I found one and that seems nice. I'm posting that solution below and accepting that (very easy and short just for type hints), but I'll certainly use this approach for other modifications.